# Why use a fully connected layer for attention?

Tags: natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, attention

In the paper [Neural Machine Translation by Jointly Learning to Align and Translate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf), attention is used with a single fully connected layer. Specifically, in the auto-regressive set up (equation 4), the context vector c_i is computed using attention  from all the annotations (equation 5).

I'm curious why a fully connected layer is used here and not some other architecture that captures "locality" better: the relationship between adjacent states should be similar independent of where in the sentence they occur. I.e. the relationship between state 1 and 2 should be analogous or similar to the relationship between states n and n+1? However, the fully connected layer treats these two relationships as completely independent weights: a[1,2] vs a[n,n+1].

[image]